# How do I extract specific attributes from JSON using copy(JSON.stringify(Object.entries while filtering out unneeded attributes in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, chromium, console.log

The data I'm looking to process is a form of web-based game data communicated through JSON. I'm trying to do statistical analysis on correlations between let's say attributes `api_ship_id` and `api_lv`. I was following a [Tutorial](https://kancolle-fleetanalysis.firebaseapp.com/#/) (Mostly in Japanese) on how to export some JSON files with a chrome plugin. On the other hand, I have a chromium-based web browser that supports similar JSON export but has a slightly different structure. The code this tutorial provided as was

```
copy(JSON.stringify(Object.entries(temp1.model.ship._map).map(([, v]) => v._o).filter(v => v.api_locked), ['api_ship_id', 'api_lv', 'api_kyouka', 'api_exp']))
```

but my chromium-based browser have trouble parsing this JSON when going filter.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'api_locked' of undefined.

tl;dr: The 4 catagories I want are
`['api_ship_id', 'api_lv', 'api_kyouka', 'api_exp']`

JSON:

```
{"1": {
    "api_id": 1,
    "api_sortno": 1337,
    "api_ship_id": 237,
    "api_lv": 70,
    "api_exp": [
        274115,
        885,
        91
    ],
    "api_nowhp": 30,
    "api_maxhp": 30,
    "api_soku": 10,
    "api_leng": 1,
    "api_slot": [
        -1,
        -1,
        -1,
        -1,
        -1
    ],
    "api_onslot": [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "api_slot_ex": 0,
    "api_kyouka": [
        37,
        51,
        34,
        36,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "api_backs": 4,
    "api_fuel": 15,
    "api_bull": 20,
    "api_slotnum": 3,
    "api_ndock_time": 0,
    "api_ndock_item": [
        0,
        0
    ],
    "api_srate": 4,
    "api_cond": 49,
    "api_karyoku": [
        49,
        49
    ],
    "api_raisou": [
        79,
        79
    ],
    "api_taiku": [
        49,
        49
    ],
    "api_soukou": [
        49,
        49
    ],
    "api_kaihi": [
        76,
        89
    ],
    "api_taisen": [
        48,
        59
    ],
    "api_sakuteki": [
        29,
        39
    ],
    "api_lucky": [
        12,
        59
    ],
    "api_locked": 1,
    "api_locked_equip": 0
},
"2": {
    "api_id": 2,
    "api_sortno": 1350,
    "api_ship_id": 250,
    "api_lv": 29,
    "api_exp": [
        40635,
        2865,
        1
    ],
    "api_nowhp": 31,
    "api_maxhp": 31,
    "api_soku": 10,
    "api_leng": 1,
    "api_slot": [
        1921,
        356,
        -1,
        -1,
        -1
    ],
    "api_onslot": [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "api_slot_ex": 0,
    "api_kyouka": [
        22,
        37,
        15,
        19,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "api_backs": 4,
    "api_fuel": 15,
    "api_bull": 20,
    "api_slotnum": 3,
    "api_ndock_time": 0,
    "api_ndock_item": [
        0,
        0
    ],
    "api_srate": 2,
    "api_cond": 73,
    "api_karyoku": [
        36,
        49
    ],
    "api_raisou": [
        65,
        79
    ],
    "api_taiku": [
        38,
        49
    ],
    "api_soukou": [
        33,
        49
    ],
    "api_kaihi": [
        58,
        89
    ],
    "api_taisen": [
        34,
        59
    ],
    "api_sakuteki": [
        17,
        39
    ],
    "api_lucky": [
        12,
        59
    ],
    "api_locked": 1,
    "api_locked_equip": 0
},
"3": {
    "api_id": 3,
    "api_sortno": 1302,
    "api_ship_id": 202,
    "api_lv": 30,
    "api_exp": [
        43597,
        2903,
        3
    ],
    "api_nowhp": 30,
    "api_maxhp": 30,
    "api_soku": 10,
    "api_leng": 1,
    "api_slot": [
        2131,
        5074,
        -1,
        -1,
        -1
    ],
    "api_onslot": [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "api_slot_ex": 0,
    "api_kyouka": [
        18,
        27,
        16,
        17,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "api_backs": 4,
    "api_fuel": 15,
    "api_bull": 20,
    "api_slotnum": 3,
    "api_ndock_time": 0,
    "api_ndock_item": [
        0,
        0
    ],
    "api_srate": 2,
    "api_cond": 61,
    "api_karyoku": [
        32,
        49
    ],
    "api_raisou": [
        62,
        79
    ],
    "api_taiku": [
        32,
        49
    ],
    "api_soukou": [
        30,
        49
    ],
    "api_kaihi": [
        60,
        89
    ],
    "api_taisen": [
        34,
        59
    ],
    "api_sakuteki": [
        16,
        39
    ],
    "api_lucky": [
        12,
        49
    ],
    "api_locked": 1,
    "api_locked_equip": 0
}}
```

What I've tried

```
copy(JSON.stringify(Object.entries(temp2).map(([, v]) => v._o), ['api_ship_id', 'api_lv', 'api_kyouka', 'api_exp']))
```

Result: `undefined`

Ideal results:

```
{"api_ship_id": 237,"api_lv": 70,"api_kyouka": [37,51,34,36,0,0,0],"api_exp": [40635,2865,1],}
{"api_ship_id": 238,"api_lv": 68,"api_kyouka": [30,0,4,6,0,0,0],"api_exp": [565,285,1],}
```

Comment: The error means that somewhere you are accessing `thing.api_locked` and that `thing` is undefined.  So looking at your code you can figure out that the .filter() operation is not working because the .map() operation before is returning undefined (probably because there's no `_o` property on v)

Comment: TY i'll look into it.